# Delimiter for CSV file in IIB

Tags: mapping, integration, delimiter, dfdl

I am developing an integration in IIB and one of the requirements for output (multiple CSV files) is a comma delimiter instead of semicollon. Semicolon is is on the input. Im using two mapping nodes to produce separate files from one input, but struggle to find option for delimiter.

There are two mapping nodes that uses xsd shemas and .maps to produce output.

First mapping creates canonical dfdl format that is ready to be parsed to multipe files in second mapping node.

There is not much code. just setup in IIB

I would like to produce comma separated CSV instead of semicollon.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. You can simply view and edit the xsd code in text editor and change the delimiter there.